# I want to add transition effect with every image of the slide show which i created so how i will add?

Tags: iphone

Here is few code related to my slide show,What i want is to add transition effect on each img.Img  will be picked from library and add the transition effect on that img  so when we play the slide the image with specific transition should be played means when 1 transition will disapear with their trans. effect another will appear with their transition effect..

```
   - (void)addPhoto
{
if (imagePicker == nil) 
{

  imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  imagePicker.allowsImageEditing = YES; 

  imagePicker.sourceType =
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
  imagePicker.delegate = self; 
}

returnFromImagePicker = YES; 


[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
} 


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:
(NSDictionary *)editInfo
{
[pictures addObject:img]; 

 UITableView *table = (UITableView *)self.view;


  [table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath
  indexPathForRow:pictures.count - 1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:
  UITableViewRowAnimationRight];


[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 } 


- (void)addEffect
{
if (effectSheet == nil) 
{

  effectSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose Effect"
     delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil
     otherButtonTitles:@"Fade", @"Slide In", nil];
} 

[effectSheet showInView:self.view];
} 


- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:
 (NSInteger)buttonIndex
{   
effect = buttonIndex;

}
```

Comment: Can you give us some more details and some code which you are using to to apply the transition effect.

Comment: @Dev Singh please make the question clear,what do u want?

Comment: @Nick,Nipin please help me out from this. Now I uploaded code and the details about the question

Answer (score 0):

UIView has a class method by which you can transition from one view to another with a transition. Use it like this:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:currentView toView:newView duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:nil];
```

For more information refer to [Apple's UIView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).